# Merge dataframes using reduce- how to add the merge by option

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, reduce

My code:

```
df1 <- data.frame("X1"=c("John","Sam","Dave"),"X2"=c(21,22,25))
df2 <- data.frame("X1"=c("John","Sam"),"X2"=c(22,25))
df3 <- data.frame("X1"=c("John","Sam","Dave"),"X2"=c("US","SA","NZ"))
mylist <- list(df1,df2,df3)
merged= Reduce(function (...) merge(..., all= T), mylist)
```

My output is:

```
    X1 X2
1 Dave 25
2 Dave NZ
3 John 21
4 John 22
5 John US
6  Sam 22
7  Sam 25
8  Sam SA
```

However, the output that I want is

```
  names X1    X2.x    X2.y
1  Dave  25    NA      NZ
2  John  21    22      US
3   Sam  22    25      SA
```

I understand that I can get the desired output if I name the columns differently, but that is not an option here. Specifically, I want to know how to add the "by= "X1" argument with the Reduce function as used in merge function alone.

Comment: `merged= Reduce(function (...) merge(..., all= T, by = "X1"), mylist)`

Answer (score 2):

what @caldwellst said in the comments, but with some preparation (like keying).

```
library( data.table )
#set as data.table
lapply( mylist, setDT )
#set keys
lapply( mylist, setkey, X1)
#merge
Reduce( function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mylist )

#      X1 X2.x X2.y X2
# 1: Dave   25   NA NZ
# 2: John   21   22 US
# 3:  Sam   22   25 SA
```